# Question of understanding - probability

Tags: probability

A man has 2 red and 1 white balls in an urn. All balls are equally likely to get pulled, and the man pulls two of them randomly. My question: Is there a difference between the task "He pulls two times a balls, one by one, from the urn" and "he pulls two balls at once from the urn"?

My thoughts: No, there is no difference since when one considers the sample spaces of the two tasks, they are the same, i.e. $\Omega = (\{r_1, r_2, w\}\times\{r_1, r_2, w\})\setminus \{(r_1, r_1), (r_2, r_2), (w, w)\}$, where $r  \space\hat{=} $ "red ball" etc.

Comment: You are correct.  Intuitively, suppose he pulls two balls at once but looks at one before the other.  How is that different from pulling them one at a time?

Comment: @saulspatz thanks, that makes sense!